# If the universe is spatially infinite, and if something (A) is possible, does that mean the thing (A) happens?

Tags: cosmology, universe, probability

Assuming that the universe is spatially infinite, extending outwards in all directions without end, and is consistent with what we have thus far observed, and predict to find (and predict to be out beyond our reach), in the cosmos, then:

Does everything that is physically possible, happen? Just by merit of being physically possible in our universe, does 'it,' happen, somewhere out in the universe?

P.S. Doesn't everything that's possible happen an infinite number of times? The only practical difference being how often something occurs, which would be based upon its likelihood of happening, based upon physical laws.

Comment: I do not understand the question: A fact which *never* occurs in the Universe (= everything existed, exists, will exist) is *impossible* by definition. Otherwise I cannot understand what "possible" means. However it has nothing to do with the spatial extension of the Universe. It is more related with pure logic or philosophy...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22187/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22390/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

I could probably go along with this assertion; except that the *observable* universe is not infinite. We can only see light reaching us from about 13 billion light years away. The stars/galaxies etc that formed in those distant regions are now even further away from us, but nevertheless, the observable universe is finite.

[Expansion of the Universe, will light from some galaxies never reach us?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129980/expansion-of-the-universe-will-light-from-some-galaxies-never-reach-us?rq=1)

[Size of the universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/size-of-the-universe)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe

Therefore if an event is possible, yet extremely unlikely (the emergence of intelligent life *might* be an example), it may still be rare within our observable universe, even if common in the universe as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would appear to be "yes", assuming every possible state exists at least once. [Tegmark](http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/crazy.html) did a calculation of the approximate distance between "You" and the next identical instance of "You" in such a universe as 10^10^29 meters away

Comment: The number you've given is a nice way of saying : This is what you get if you ask such questions.

Comment: Yes, it's a long walk if you want verification :-)